# Why should I put '#' before the path when routing with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, routes

When routing in Angular views we add the following.  I don't understand the need to add `#`; if I remove it, I get a 404 Error.

`a href="#/AddNewOrder"`

Comment: You don't need the # if you are using HTML5 pushstate. Take a look at @user1177476's answer. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting `#` in URL indicates start of the [hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.hash) part, which is used to address elements inside a single page. In modern single-page web applications, this can be used to address application states.

If you don't put the `#` there, you're changing the [path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.pathname), which means you're creating a new URL and prompting the browser to load the content at that new URL instead of the current page.

---

*As other posters have suggested, you don't have to use hashes when using [`html5mode`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/docs/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider). I left it out, because it brings a few challenges of its own, which I feel to be outside the scope of the question.*

Comment: It is probably a good idea to use HTMLPushState for most SPA -- not requiring a #.

Answer (score 1):

[enter link description here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)You don't have to. You can configure your URLs to look like normal URLs, but in reality they will still work the same way.

Check https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location
And refer to html5mode

It will only work in modern browsers though. Old browsers will still show the hash. But the cool thing is that you can write your URLs the old/normal way.

Answer (score 0):

`#` or fragment identifier is a way to indicate a specific portion of a single document. Without the #, the url corresponds to a different page.

For example `www.yoursite.com/page` links to the `/page` location of your website, while `www.yoursite.com/#/location` points to the same index page of your website but at a specfic point in the web page `#location`, or in your case, a different template view.

Angular routing can not load different templates for different server urls. It is specifically designed for single-page applications and any loading of partial views or templates has to happen on the same web-page or location. Hence only the fragment part of the url changes when using angularjs routing.

More information about fragments can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier